# Populating array with slide ranges

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to loop through all slides, and if condition applies, store the slide index into one array. This is my code, but I get an error :

> Slides (unknown member): Illegal value. Bad type: expected 1D array
>   of Variants, Integers, Longs or Strings.

Thanks!

```
Private Sub folienauswahlen()
Dim arr() As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim folie As slide
    With ActivePresentation
        For Each folie In .Slides
            If .Slides.Range(folie).SlideIndex < 3 Then
            arr(b) = .Slides.Range(folie).SlideIndex
            ReDim Preserve arr(0 To b) As Long
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber to get the slide range you need?  Since you are only using the sides greater than 3.

Comment: 3 is just an example. Instead of 3 it will get a number out of a textbox.

Comment: That is still usable, just make the range from your input value to the .slides.count and since you are just populating the array with numbers, you can do that without looping through the presentation slides.

Comment: But if I delete the loop through all slides, how can it detect automatically all the slides where the conditions apply?

Comment: The goal of the code is first to detect ALL of the slides and then to delete them in the final step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
Private Sub folienauswahlen()
    ReDim arr(1 To 1) As Long
    Dim b As Long
    Dim folie As Slide
    With ActivePresentation
        b = 1
        For Each folie In .Slides
            If folie.SlideIndex < 3 Then
                ReDim Preserve arr(1 To b) As Long
                arr(b) = folie.SlideIndex
                b = b + 1

            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

In VBA, you don't need `.Slides.Range(folie).SlideIndex` constructs. You get the object in the for each variable.

Comment: More efficient to initialise and redim to slides.count-1  at start then redim preserve at end once to b?

Comment: hello sam! I always get 0 as an answer with that code ..:/

Comment: Updated the snippet

Comment: Thank you! Still there is a problem: I always get back only 1 value, which is exactly `If folie.SlideIndex < 3` **-1** --> in this example 3-1= 2. But actually the array should store two values (1 and 2).

Comment: I can't understand the purpose of all that: if you want to store the slides index of those slides whose index is less than `3`, then you don't need to loop through slides at all and just go `ReDim arr(1 To 2)` and `arr(1)=1` and `arr(2)=2`. Or what am I missing?

Comment: I understand it to be placeholder code to keep the post short

Comment: I'm not getting you. But let's wait for karen's feedback

Comment: Sam is right. I have two columns ("from"- "to") with each about 10 textboxes where I can put in numbers (e.g. slides from 5 to 8). Hence I can define several slide ranges. I want to store this ranges so in the end they can be deleted at once. If I delet them immediately in the loop, the ranges for the next loop will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing an array to have all the slide indexes above the number you input (in your example it's 3)  This will construct an array of all indexes above the input number.  But it seems you could delete the slide above the input number without an array or looping through the slide. You could just delete all slides with a slide index greater than your input number.

This will get you your array.

```
Private Sub folienauswahlen()
Dim arr() As Long
Dim b As Long
  Lslide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
  b = InputBox("enter the slide number")

      ReDim arr(0 To Lslide - b - 1) As Long
      For x = 0 To Lslide - b - 1
          arr(x) = b
          b = b + 1
     Next x


End Sub
```